# SQL handles and how to create one properly?

Tags: sql, c, sql-server

This code does not work (i got this from another question) because it has too few parameters: sqldirect needs a handler and a length.

I know from a high level what a handle is, but I only ever see them used when prepping and binding statements, not just a statement that is directly executed once like this. I'm learning SQL and I find all of this extremely confusing.

Can someone explain how to make a handle for this code, and perhaps direct me to a good SQL book or learning resource? Its hard to find any information on this online that I can follow.

```
for (n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
    char sql[1000];
    sprintf(sql, "insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(%d,%d)", n, n);
    SQLExecDirect(sql);
}
```

Edit: oops.. i thought I fixed that error in the code i posted. this question assumes that the sprintf line is NOT missing a parameter:

```
for (n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
    char sql[1000];
    sprintf(sql, "insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(%d,%d)", n, n);
    SQLExecDirect(sql);
}
```

Comment: `sprintf(sql, "insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(%d,%d)", n, n);` you never assigned sql any value.

Answer (score 1):

As pointed out by @DanielE, you forget the first paramter of `sprintf`, anyway this is more appropriate in a `for` loop:

```
SQLPrepare("insert into mytable (cola, colb) values(?,?);");
for (n = 0; n < 10000; n++) {
    SQLBindParameter(1, n);
    SQLBindParameter(2, n);
    SQLExecute;
}
```

Comment: warning: passing argument 1 of ‘SQLPrepare’ makes integer from pointer without a cast
error: too few arguments to function ‘SQLPrepare’

I'm guessing this is the same reason as before.. no handler

Comment: You need to [allocate a connection handler](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms712455%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), take a look to this [example](http://books.google.es/books?id=eprEAgAAQBAJ&pg=PA87&lpg=PA87&dq=SQLAllocHandle+SQLPrepare&source=bl&ots=6UqlhNgC43&sig=moNtEKmnKz102Ph2RCWZ57mDCfE&hl=es&sa=X&ei=03b3U5yME5XvaKGMgrgO&ved=0CGgQ6AEwCDgK#v=onepage&q=SQLAllocHandle%20SQLPrepare&f=false)

Answer (score 0):

First, Your statment:

```
SQLExecDirect(sql);
```

Is missing some parameters.  the prototype for *SQLExecDirect* requires 3 arguments, including handle:

```
SQLRETURN SQLExecDirect(
     SQLHSTMT     StatementHandle,
     SQLCHAR *    StatementText,
     SQLINTEGER   TextLength);
```

Here is a snippet showing how to obtain SQL handles, including *SQLHSTMT*:

```
SQLHENV env;
SQLHDBC dbc;
SQLHSTMT stmt;

SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, SQL_NULL_HANDLE, &env);
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_DBC, env, &dbc);
/* connect to the data source */
SQLAllocHandle(SQL_HANDLE_ENV, dbc, &stmt);
/* do something with the statement handle e.g. issue sql */
```

With the handle obtained, and with the sprintf correction shown in a different post, the call can be made like this:

```
SQLExecDirect(stmt, sql, strlen(sql)); //sql is string containing statement
```

You also asked for links.  Here are a few: (there are many more)

***[Handles and environment related](http://www.easysoft.com/developer/languages/c/odbc_tutorial.html#odbc_handles)***

***[SQLExecDirect](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms713611%28v=vs.85%29.aspx)***

Another ***[SQLExecDirect](http://odbc.net/api/index.shtml?SQLExecDirect)***